# Parrot speakers don't work but headphones work

Tags: linux, audio, speakers, parrot-os

i have just installed parrot 4.11 alongside windows 11 on a different partition and everything works fine but sometimes the sound comes out from the speakers and from the headphones and sometimes it only comes out from headphones and if i remove them i hear no sound.i tried of course rebooting it but it didn't work. by the way i want to mention that i have faced the same problem when running the live version from a usb and i am facing it now again with the system installed.

running on: hp pavilion x360

screenshot for the hardware in sound settings
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9VDC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved.
I don't know what was the direct reason which solved it but i will say what i did hopefully that it might help.

I updated my source list to the following

first

```
sudo pluma /etc/apt/sources.list.d/parrot.list
```

update your source list with this list

```
deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ rolling main contrib non-free
#deb-src https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ rolling main contrib non-free
deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ rolling-security main contrib non-free
#deb-src https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ rolling-security main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
deb http://security.debian.org stretch/updates main
```

after that

```
sudo apt-get update
```

next i installed pavucontrol

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

then i used my windows for some hours and when i returned to linux sound was working correctly i think we can say here reboot and test it

hope this helps